# resize div content based on browser window size

Tags: html, css

*So let's say I have this:*
http://cl.ly/image/3S333B212D0Q/1.jpg

*When i resize the browser window height, this happens:*
http://cl.ly/image/1y0n2r3k3f3T/22.jpg

*But i want this to happen instead:*
http://cl.ly/image/2t1T1w1t1q1N/3.jpg

How can I accomplish this? I know I should have posted code, but i don't even know where to start.

If anyone could point out where to start looking.

Comment: it would be so awesome if existed a js plugin for this...

Comment: I don't think he wants a JavaScript answer...

Comment: Edit your question and, share your code, please.

Comment: Can you please provide us yout code? Or fiddle?\

Answer (score -1):

Add this `styles` to your image, to make it `responsive`:

```
    max-width:100% !important;
    height:auto;
    display:block;
```

Also, I suggest to use [Bootstrap Framework from Twitter](http://getbootstrap.com/)

Comment: try also adding `overflow-y: hidden;`

Comment: and for the other things that aren't images?

Comment: then apply it *only* to the div

Comment: @Jonhz take a look of bootstrap grid system: http://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/

Comment: i want to do that to this thing: https://jsfiddle.net/ytLhfmxn/1/    i need to have a load of progresses bar in any screen size without scrolling bar.

Comment: The `progressbar divs` have `width: 100%;` style. You copy the css, and modify as you want in your html document.

Comment: @alessadro what about height?

Comment: Express it in terms of a percentage, and add `overflow-y: hidden;` suggested by @ThePixelBug

Comment: guys, i do know bootstrap, but my problem is with height, and not with width.

Answer (score -1):

You can use jQuery device width, height. [Check this out](https://jsfiddle.net/Lnxde8eL/1/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var widnow_wth = $( window ).width();
    var height_wth = $( window ).height();
    $(".content").css('min-width',widnow_wth);
    $(".content").css('min-height',height_wth);

});
```